# Transmission fluid in coolant overflow tank

Tags: pontiac, radiator-overflow

This is a 2004 Pontiac Aztec.

I have transmission fluid in my coolant overflow tank.

What would cause that?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the transmission cooler has failed - the trans cooler has the hot oil passing through it next to water so the water absorbs the heat.

This may be a separate radiator or built into the main engine cooling radiator.

This needs to be checked, as if the water is getting into the transmission oil it can damage the transmission.